# Compiled C# Linq Expression<Func<T>> and querying Mongo

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, lambda, mongorepository

I've inherited some code from a former employee that queries a mongo DB using compiled Linq expressions and the [MongoRepository library](https://github.com/RobThree/MongoRepository) (which sits on top of the MongoDB C# driver).

These were taking a long time to run - usually around 6 minutes(!) and causing problems with controller methods that used them.

So I've simplified the code and removed the call to `.Compile()` the lambda expression and this has seemed to solve the issue (takes <10s to run now).

**My questions is: why does compiling this expression cause problems when querying mongo?**

This was the gist of the original code (hacked out, so out of context sorry):

```
public class BaseMongoRepository<T> : MongoRepository<T, Guid> where T : IEntity<Guid> {

    protected BaseMongoRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

    protected bool IsSatisfiedBy(T entity) {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> func = x => x != null && x.ToString() == "foo"; // query was passed in, but you get the idea
        var predicate = func.Compile(); // THIS LINE??
        return predicate(entity);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find() {
        return base.collection.AsQueryable().Where(IsSatisfiedBy);
    }
}
```

And I simplified it to something that just uses a regular predicate `Func`:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Find() {
    return base.collection.AsQueryable().Where(x => x != null && x.ToString() == "foo");
}
```

Any thoughts most appreciated!

Comment: What if collection has 1,000,000 entities and for each it has to *compile* the expression into delegate. It's a relatively time-consuming operation and if repeated 1,000,000 times it might take forever to execute a query like this. It would be far more logical to save Func in a field or in some cases a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

The expression can be converted by a provider to a real sql query, but a delegate can not be interpreted.

The `predicate` variable in this code:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> func = x => x != null && x.ToString() == "foo";
var predicate = func.Compile();
```

is essentially the same as:

```
Func<T, bool> predicate = x => x != null && x.ToString() == "foo";
```

When you use such a delegate, all data from the database is transferred into memory and after that the predicate is applied.

Pseudo code example:

```
// Using the delegate:
var data = dbContext.Users.Where(usr => IsSatisfiedBy(usr)).ToList();
// This will result in the following steps:
var userList = ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM Users"); // all users are fetched.
var satisfied = userList.Where(usr => IsSatisfiedBy(usr))

// Using an expression:
var data = dbContext.Users.Where(usr => usr.Name == "foo");
// This will result in the following step:
var satisfied = ExecuteQuery("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name = 'foo'"); // Filtered before returned to caller.
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the performance problem is to record all the records of the related object and then filter it out. First you need to create the query and register from mongo db.

review for soruce code
https://github.com/fsefacan/MongoDbRepository

Comment: Your answer looks really unclear to me. What does _record all the records_ mean and what do you mean by _register_? Can you elaborate?